# Cannot get Ajax result from a Vue method to data()s returned variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this component, I have just started working with components until this point where there I am trying to fetch data via ajax, when `console.log`ing inside the method - I get the actual result, but the result isn't returned.

1. What is it that I'm not understanding (In vanilla js when doing the same from an object, it works fine.. so why in Vue it doesn't work? What's the reason from behind the scenes?)
2. How can I fetch data using `$.ajax`?
3. What are my other alternatives and why? (I know of Axio, never used it, not sure why to use it if I can use fetch, which btw, fetch didn't work for me too - that's why I went back to $.ajax).

---

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const Dashboard_testcomponent      = () => import('../vue/dashboard/test/testcomponent.vue');


let routes = [
    {
        path: '/main',
        component: Dashboard,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'testcomponent',
                component: Dashboard_testcomponent
            }
        ]
    }
];


window.router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
```

---

testcomponent.vue:

```
<script>
    import Form    from "../../components/Form.vue";
    import Tabs    from "../../components/Tabs.vue";

    export default {
        name: 'testcomponent',
        components: {
            Form,
            Tabs
        },
        data() {
            return {
                reportType: 'testreport', 
                dates: {},
                list: {} 
        }
        ,
        created() {
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        destroyed() {
        },
        watch: {
        },
        methods: {
            // Submit form
            formSubmit: function(data) {
                console.log('Submit form here');
                console.log(data);

                // SetLoader();

                this.list = this.getList();
                console.log(this.getList());
                console.log(this.List);
            }, 
            // Fetch List By List type 
            getList: function() {

                axios.post('/call/api/getList', {
                    'reportType': this.reportType
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status === true) {
                        console.log(response);
                        return response.data;
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });


            }
        }
    }
</scrip1t>


<templat e>

        <Form 
            :useGroupFilter="true"
            :useDateRange="true"
            @submit="formSubmit"
        />


</template>
```

Comment: if u r using jquery ajax, u need to install and import it in your component. U might also need to add it as a plugin. Did u do all that?

Comment: I recommend you to use Axios with Vue.js . It's way easier to manage. https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: @TeddyMcZieuwa Done that, jquery works well

Comment: please post your error log also

Answer (score 0):

Install Axios for in your project directory

```
$ npm install axios
```

import in app.js or in the component which you want

```
<script>
//optional import for individual component
import axios from "axios";
</script>

    //if you have imported in app.js
        Vue.use(axios);
```

then make axios call like:

```
      let reqData = {
        p_Params1: '',
        p_Params2: '',
        p_Params3...: ''
      };

      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/sample_sub/sample.ext",
        crossdomain: true,
        data: $.param(reqData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
//your resposne here
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**Note! by default axios does not parse the data to json so use $.param**

Comment: which doesn't really answer #3. and doesn't answer #2 at all :(

Comment: did you import ajax in your project? then it should have worked  or check your import

Comment: and by default vue recommend using axois for netrwork calls so give a shot for it, and it is very simple and easy like ajax

Comment: but why use that and not fetch?

Comment: fetch are saying fetch api or Ajax?

Comment: in vue js you can use ajax, but did you import ajax in your project

Comment: I did `import axios from 'axios'; import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'; Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)` to get axios, and then used is as in your example inside my "getList" method - and still do not get a json variable returned

Comment: and also if its not working try to import axios in your component  even i had the issue when i imported in app.js

Comment: `ReferenceError: axios is not defined at VueComponent.getList` will update in a sec

Comment: In response to Q#3 from the [Vuejs cookbook](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html): The Fetch API is a powerful native API for these types of requests. You may have heard that one of the benefits of the Fetch API is that you don’t need to load an external resource in order to use it, which is true! Except… that it’s not fully supported yet, so you will still need to use a polyfill. There are also some gotchas when working with this API, which is why many prefer to use axios for now. This may very well change in the future though.

Comment: `ReferenceError: axios is not defined at VueComponent.getList` you get this because you have not imported. Try importing as I have done in my answer. The above method is perfectly working as i expected just try this its sure does.

Answer (score 0):

In you code getList is not returning anything, because axios.post is async function and executes later.
You should assign response data in .then callback. 
Something like:

```js
getList: function() {
    axios.post('/call/api/getList', {
        'reportType': this.reportType
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        // if (response.status === true) { (if 'then' fired means that it succeeded already)
            console.log(response);
            this.list = response.data;
        // }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```